# ActiveRecord Postgres 8-10x slower on DotCloud (EC2) production vs Macbook air development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, amazon-ec2, dotcloud

I have a Rails 3.2.12 app set up locally and on DotCloud. I'm seeing very slow ActiveRecord (postgres) performance on Dotcloud and can't work out why:

**Page Load Macbook Air (rails app in development mode):**

```
Completed 200 OK in 617ms (Views: 361.3ms | ActiveRecord: 39.1ms)
```

**Page Load DotCloud (rails app in production mode, identical DB and page):**

```
Completed 200 OK in 796ms (Views: 315.3ms | ActiveRecord: 329.4ms)
```

This is not an erratic time, but the standard performance delta on all page loads. My database is only 16MB, so not large. Memory allocation on the postgres service is sufficient (128MB), with only 30MB being utilized. I checked my local postgres.conf and the settings are default, untuned postgresql.app settings.

Is this poor performance just what to expect in the cloud? Is it network latency between the web server and db server?

Would very much appreciate thoughts on how to debug & fix this!

Comment: what's the hardware in the cloud? Don't Air's have super fast SSDs?

Comment: Dotcloud is on EC2 so it's whatever they were on. But with a 16MB database, postgres should be using memory and caching the whole thing, not relying on disk... Any way to tune this?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is enable query duration logging in PostgreSQL on both machines then compare query durations. See if it's a DB level issue or something higher level. Also: What's the machine's overall memory state? Disk I/O load?

Answer (score 1):

As a [dotCloud](http://www.dotcloud.com/) employee, I have to tell you that if you want a thorough look at your application to see why it's not performing to your expectations, you have to [file a support ticket](http://support.dotcloud.com). I should also tell you that if you're in sandbox mode, you can expect lesser performance compared to if you were in one of the paying tiers (such as Live or Enterprise).

As a fellow developer, however, I can quickly point out two key differences between your local dev environment and your [dotCloud](http://www.dotcloud.com/) environment.

1. Your dev environment runs your DBMS (PostgreSQL) and your rails app on the same host, eliminating any noticeable latency caused by round-trips to the database. With dotCloud, these are likely to be on separate hosts and possibly even in separate datacenters.
2. Your dev environment probably uses a Solid State Drive (SSD) (depending on the age of your MacBook Air) and you just moved into EBS (Amazon Elastic Block Store), a form of network-attached storage (on hard disk drives).

Between these two changes, I'm not totally shocked by the increase in response time, but my curiosity is piqued by your ActiveRecord time increasing by 290ms while your overall response time only increased by 180ms.

I don't want to speculate where your response time is being eaten up, so once again I recommend you [file a support ticket at support.dotcloud.com](http://support.dotcloud.com) as soon as possible so that we can take a closer look. If and when you do, mention my name or this StackOverflow thread and include the URL for your app.

Comment: Thanks Charles. The application is running in live mode. I'm assuming that with such a small db, it should be mostly in cache . ram and disk IO throughput shouldn't matter. Either way, given local is running in dev mode, which doesn't cache classes, etc, you'd expect a performance increase on production to say the very least. I've filed a ticket for John.